# Returning stored array values from functions in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am writing a program where the input is a number and it is converted to binary string and the binary bits are stored in an array. It is done for two/(or more) numbers and after the conversion I want to perform the bitwise xor operation between the two bit strings. For this I want to define a function and get outputs for different numbers. How to do that ?
My try

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int decTobin1(int decimal, int *binary1[6])
{
    int binary1[6]{};
    int round{};
    int rem;
    while (decimal != 0)
    {
        *binary1[round] = decimal % 2;
        decimal /= 2;
        ++round;
    }
}
int decTobin2(int decimal, int *binary2[6])
{
    int binary2[6]{};
    int round{};
    int rem;
    while (decimal != 0)
    {
        *binary2[round] = decimal % 2;
        decimal /= 2;
        ++round;
    }
}
/*int decTobin3(int decimal, int* binary3[6])
{
    int binary3[6]{};
    int round{};
    int rem;
    while (decimal != 0)
    {
        *binary3[round] = decimal % 2;
        decimal /= 2;
        ++round;
    }
}*/
int main()
{
    int binary1[6], binary2[6]; //binary3[6];
    cout << "Enter a number :";
    cout << "Enter a number :";
    int num1, num2;
    cin >> num1 >> num2;
    int num1 = decTobin1(num1, &binary1);
    int num2 = decTobin2(num2, &binary2);
    //int newkey2 = decTobin3(num3,&binary3);
    cout << "Print :";
    for (int k{}; k < 6; ++k)
    {
        cout << binary1[k] << endl;
    }
    for (int k{}; k < 6; ++k)
    {
        cout << binary2[k] << endl;
    }
    /*for(int k{};k<6;++k){
        cout << binary3[k] << endl;
    }*/
}
```

second try ...

```
using namespace std;
struct binary
{
    int binary1[6]{};
};
binary decTobin()
{
    int round{};
    int decimal;
    int binary1[6]{};
    int rem;
    while (decimal != 0)
    {
        binary1[round] = decimal % 2;
        decimal /= 2;
        ++round;
    }
    binary temp{binary1[0], binary1[1], binary1[2], binary1[3], binary1[4], binary1[5]};
    return temp;
}
int main()
{
    int binary1[6], binary2[6]; //binary3[6];
    cout << "Enter a number :";
    //cout << "Enter a number :";
    int num1, num2;
    cin >> num1; // >> num2 ;
    binary zero{decTobin()};
    //int num1   = decTobin(num1,&binary1);
    //int num2 = decTobin2(num2,&binary2);
    //int newkey2 = decTobin3(num3,&binary3);
    cout << "Print :";
    for (int k{}; k < 6; ++k)
    {
        cout << zero.binary1[k] << endl;
    }
    /*for(int k{};k<6;++k){
        cout << binary3[k] << endl;
    }*/
}
```

I tried to run this but it crashed. Can anyone help me out. I basically want to learn the way to return array values. Also I am new to programming and learning so little bit explanation will be helpful. Thank You.

Comment: In your top try you declare functions to return `int` but the functions don't return anything. In your second version you do not initialize varibles before reading them. Both these things makes your programs have undefined behavior.

Comment: what do you want to me to edit then ? any suggestion.

Comment: It depends on what you want the functions to do. If they are not supposed to return anything, make them `void` instead of `int`. The uninitialized `decimal` in the second example needs to be initialized - but with what I don't know. I don't understand what it's being used for.

Comment: I little bit stated what I want to do in the question. I want to give the function a number it will then convert it to binary and all the bits will be stored in an array.  Now this will be done for one more number and finally in the main function I will xor the two bit strings that I computed there. How to do that ?

Comment: Look at `int decTobin1(int decimal, int *binary1[6])` for example. You've declared it to return an `int` - but it does not return anything. I don't know what it should return. Do you? If it shouldn't return anything, make it `void`. What is `decimal` supposed to be? You have a loop `while (decimal != 0)` but you never initializa `decimal` to anything. Where should it start?